# Jekyll on Windows not compiling SASS

Tags: ruby, windows, sass, jekyll

When trying to run `bundle exec jekyll serve` on a Windows 10 machine, this error occurs:

```
jekyll 3.7.4 | Error: File to import not found or unreadable: reset.
Load paths:
  C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/minima-2.5.0/_sass
  C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/minima-2.5.0/_sass on line 6
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── _config.yml
├── README.md
├── _sass
|   ├── _reset.scss
|   └── _variables.scss
├── assets
|   ├── styles
|   |   └── design.scss
├── .gitignore
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
└── index.md
```

Please note that this works on my Mac (I just cloned the git repository and tried to serve on Windows).

I've tried adding this to `_config.yml` but it did not change anything.

```
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ChristianHagelid Not sure if it's relevant to you anymore, but I switched to using the Linux Subsystem for Windows

Answer (score 0):

I switched from "native Windows" to `docker` to build my Jekyll pages.

[Jekyll on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jekyll/jekyll).

Create the folder `$PWD/vendor/bundle` before using docker.

`docker run -it --rm \
  --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" \
  --volume="$PWD/vendor/bundle:/usr/local/bundle" \
  jekyll/jekyll \
  jekyll build`